# Trigger an event when a checkbox is changed programmatically via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox

I need to know when a checkbox has been changed by Javascript using pure javascript.

I have setup an 'onchange' event that successfully executes when the user changes the checkbox but this doesn't work when another JS function changes it using code like the following:

```
document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked = true;
```

Is it possible to fire an event using pure JavaScript when JS either checks or unchecks a checkbox?

Answer (score 20):

You can create a `change` event with the [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)/[`initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) methods and then use the [`dispatchEvent` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) to dispatch the event from the specified `checkbox` element.

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent('change', false, true);
checkbox.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This will allow you to programmatically change the `checked` property of the element and then trigger a `change` event that will thereby fire the event listeners.

Here is a basic example:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

// Event Listener:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.checked);
});

// Programmatically change the `checked` property:'
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  triggerEvent(checkbox, 'change');
});

function triggerEvent(element, eventName) {
  var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent(eventName, false, true);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<button>Programmatically trigger 'change' event</button>
```

As an alternative, you can also use the [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event), however it has less browser support.

```
var event = new Event('change');
checkbox.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Here is an example:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

// Event Listener:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.checked);
});

// Programmatically change the `checked` property:'
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  triggerEvent(checkbox, 'change');
});

function triggerEvent (element, eventName) {
  var event = new Event(eventName);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<button>Programmatically trigger 'change' event</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to place it inside of a window.onload to make sure the dom is ready, [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("test-check");
checkbox.addEventListener("change", checked, false);

function checked(e) {
  console.log(e.target.checked)
}

var event = new Event('change');
checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
checkbox.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test-check">
 Test
</span>
```

Also you have some alternatives to the change event

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @TeChn4K How is this off the subject? It's literally the answer to the question...

Comment: He wants to know how to handle change done with programmatic `checkbox.value = <any_bool>`. Sorry but your answer is not working...

Comment: @TeChn4K The question has been edited after answer has been submitted if you look at the original title 'Event When Checkbox is changed via Javascript' it's not a case my answer being 'off the subject' it's subject changing after submission. I have updated it based on your comments

Comment: Title have been reformulated, but question didn't change at all. Stop being like this.
Btw, your updated answer still doesn't work ... You listen for `change` event, but you dispatch a `check` event.