# How to Trigger change on Javascript addEventListener after adding checked attribute on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, addeventlistener

I'm mixing javascript and jquery in my script..

```
// js variables
const checkbox1 = document.getElementById('bill-to-different-address-checkbox');
const checkbox3 = document.getElementById('bill-to-shipped-address-checkbox');`

// addeventlistener
if (checkbox1) {
    checkbox1.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
. . . . . 

// eventlistener detected checking checkbox
if (event.target.checked) {
. . . . . 

// eventlistener detected unchecking checkbox
else {
         
if (checkbox3) {
       checkbox3.checked=true;
       $("#bill-to-shipped-address-checkbox").trigger("change");
               }
. . . . .
```

What I'm needing to do is trigger this change, which is another eventlistener on the same page

```
    if (checkbox3) {
        checkbox3.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

        if (checkbox1) {
           var checkbox1checked = checkbox1.checked;
           . . . . .
```

Which does a bunch of stuff. Not relevant to the question. Debugging this `checkbox3.checked=true` does check the `#bill-to-shipped-address-checkbox` checkbox, but `$("#bill-to-shipped-address-checkbox").trigger("change");` has no noticeable effect.

What must I do to programatically push the change into that event listener whose checkbox is checked

Comment: try $(...).change() as I know, this function without arguments fires event

Comment: pure js was the way to go

Answer (score 0):

got it working with advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981509/trigger-an-event-when-a-checkbox-is-changed-programmatically-via-javascript)

```
function triggerEvent(element, eventName) {
  var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent(eventName, false, true);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

and new code for/from above

```
if (checkbox3) {
    checkbox3.checked=true;
    triggerEvent(checkbox3, 'change');
               }
```

Evidentally you cannot trigger a jquery event over javascript or vice versa. Something to that anyways. But the above code works and triggers my `addEventListener` `change` thus making everything alright with the world once again